# Ошибка загрузки таблицы стилей

Tags: php, apache, drupal

У меня есть сайт на Drupal. После очередного обновления при переходе по адресу `www.my-site.ru/sitemap.xml` я вижу следующую ошибку:

> Ошибка загрузки таблицы стилей: Во время загрузки таблицы стилей XSLT произошла ошибка в сети

На сайте стоит модуль `XML sitemap`, который и генерирует эту карту.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а что возвращает `www.my-site.ru/sitemap.xsl`?

Comment: Вот это: С этим XML-файлом не связана ни одна таблица стилей. Ниже показано дерево элементов. и собственно xml-ка, но там и близко к карте сайта нет, там нет ни информации  о самой карте, ничего,  просто  написано о том что с генерировало и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующее:

1. вставить в .htaccess строку - AddType application/xml .xsl
2. отключить в настройках "XML sitemap" пункт "Beautify XML" ("Красивый
   XML")